# sending and receiving multiple elements via MPI_Send/recv

Tags: mpi

I am starting to learning MPI. I am just starting to do simple example: I have a rectangle which is divided into two sub-boxes. I have lets say N/2 particles in each box (summing to N particles as whole). I am using two process/cores to do this job. First core handles the first sub box and second core handles second sub-box. During time, the particles cross from one sub-box to other. I am sure I have to use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv to do this job. But what I dont understand is if I have multiple particles crossing (from one core to other) each time, how do I use efficiently MPI_Send/Recv or MPI_Sendrecv ? I forgot to say I dont know the number of particles crossing each time. Sorry If the question is too simple/silly.

Comment: You pack the particle data into a contiguous array and send it all at once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @HristoIliev .... I am actually having more than two sub-boxes...I hope I could do it for more than two sub-boxes

Comment: There are plethora of parallel molecular dynamics packages like NAMD, LAMMPS, DL_POLY_4, etc. that use spatial domain decomposition techniques. So yes, you could do it for more than two sub-boxes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of options:

- You could do something simple like using an `MPI_ALLTOALL` to exchange the number of particles amongst all of the sub-boxes. Then use point-to-point communication to communicate the actual particles.
- You could use neighborhood collectives to only communicate with your neighbors using `MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALL`
- You could use point-to-point non-blocking communication between all the neighbors to exchange the number and then content of the particles.
- You could use `MPI_PROBE` to determine the number of particles that are being sent to you (with a message that somehow conveys the idea if no particles are being sent.

So, yes, it's possible. There's lots of options. You'll probably have to learn more about MPI to use any of them though.

Comment: "... with a message that somehow conveys the idea if no particles are being sent" - sending empty (zero-count) messages is perfectly legal in MPI. One doesn't even have to write special logic to handle such cases when the return value of `MPI_GET_COUNT` is used in a loop counter or something.

Comment: That would work. Whatever works for the OP. The point is that there's lots of options.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your answers.. I am surprised to see how amazing Stack Overflow is !!